# How can I find a match and update it with RegEx?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string as

```
a = "hello i am stackoverflow.com user +-"
```

Now I want to convert the escape characters in the string except the quotation marks and white space. So my expected output is :

```
a = "hello i am stackoverflow\.com user \+\-"
```

What I did so far is find all the special characters in a string except whitespace and double quote using

```
re.findall(r'[^\w" ]',a)
```

Now, once I found all the required special characters I want to update the string. I even tried `re.sub` but it replaces the special characters. Is there anyway I can do it?

Comment: In addition to the answers, something as simple as `re.sub(r'([\.+-])', r'\\\1', a)` produces your expected output.

Comment: @jedwards Dang, why didn't I think of that... Why don't you invert the RegEx and post that as an answer?

Comment: @thefourtheye that would works only for the above input. Check my second answer..

Comment: @AvinashRaj You mean to say `re.sub(r'([^\w" ])', r'\\\1', a)` will not work?

Comment: that's a nice idea. At first i thought re.escape will escape only some particular characters. But it escapes all the non-word characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape).

```
>>> a = "hello i am stackoverflow.com user +-"
>>> print(re.sub(r'\\(?=[\s"])', r'', re.escape(a)))
hello i am stackoverflow\.com user \+\-
```

> re.escape(string)
>
> Return string with all non-alphanumerics backslashed; this is useful if you want to match an arbitrary literal string that may have regular expression metacharacters in it.

`r'\\(?=[\s"])'` matches all the backslashes which exists just before to  space or double quotes. Replacing the matched backslashes with an empty string will give you the desired output.

**OR**

```
>>> a = 'hello i am stackoverflow.com user "+-'
>>> print(re.sub(r'((?![\s"])\W)', r'\\\1', a))
hello i am stackoverflow\.com user "\+\-
```

`((?![\s"])\W)` captures all the non-word characters but not of space or double quotes. Replacing the matched characters with backslash + chars inside group index 1 will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you could use backreferences with `re.sub` to achieve what your desired output:

```
import re

a = "hello i am stackoverflow.com user +-"

print re.sub(r'([^\w" ])', r'\\\1', a)   # hello i am stackoverflow\.com user \+\-
```

The replacement pattern `r'\\\1'` is just `\\` which means a literal backslash, followed `\1` which means capture group 1, the pattern captured in the parentheses in the first argument.

In other words, it will escape everything except:

- alphanumeric characters
- underscore
- double quotes
- space